# Java Pipes Synchronization

Tags: java, xml, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm working on this program which is supposed to deserialize objects from an XML using the first thread, stream it through pipes to the second thread, which will then sort it and output the results.

The thing is I get exceptions when running it, saying both read and write ends are dead.
When I try to debug though, it works fine, which makes me think it's because of faulty synchronization. Confusing, since I thought the pipes were supposed to handle that aspect. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong and point me in the right direction ?

Here's the code for the runnable:
(the relevant parts are near the end)

```
package domAPI;


import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ParserRunnable implements Runnable {
    List<Employee> myEmpls;
    Document dom;
    PipedInputStream pin;
    PipedOutputStream pout;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    int threadNr;

//  private final Object sending = new Object();
//  private final Object receiving = new Object();

    public ParserRunnable(){
        myEmpls = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    }

    public ParserRunnable(PipedOutputStream ws, int threadNr){
        myEmpls = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        pout = ws;
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(pout);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.threadNr = threadNr;
    }

    public ParserRunnable(PipedInputStream rs, int ThreadNr){
        myEmpls = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        pin = rs;
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(pin);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.threadNr = threadNr;
    }

    private void parseXmlFile(){
        //get the factory
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        try {

            //Using factory get an instance of document builder
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            //parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file
            dom = db.parse("persons.xml");


        }catch(ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        }catch(SAXException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void parseDocument(){
        //get the root element
        Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();

        //get a nodelist of <employee> elements
        NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("Employee");
        if(nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength();i++) {

                //get the employee element
                Element el = (Element)nl.item(i);

                //get the Employee object
                Employee e = getEmployee(el);

                //add it to list
                myEmpls.add(e);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * I take an employee element and read the values in, create
     * an Employee object and return it
     * @param empEl
     * @return
     */
    private Employee getEmployee(Element empEl) {

        //for each <employee> element get text or int values of 
        //name ,id, age and name
        String name = getTextValue(empEl,"Name");
        int id = getIntValue(empEl,"Id");
        int age = getIntValue(empEl,"Age");

        String type = empEl.getAttribute("type");

        //Create a new Employee with the value read from the xml nodes
        Employee e = new Employee(name,id,age,type);

        return e;
    }


    /**
     * I take a xml element and the tag name, look for the tag and get
     * the text content 
     * i.e for <employee><name>John</name></employee> xml snippet if
     * the Element points to employee node and tagName is name I will return John  
     * @param ele
     * @param tagName
     * @return
     */

    private String getTextValue(Element ele, String tagName) {
        String textVal = null;
        NodeList nl = ele.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        if(nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
            Element el = (Element)nl.item(0);
            textVal = el.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        }

        return textVal;
    }


    /**
     * Calls getTextValue and returns a int value
     * @param ele
     * @param tagName
     * @return
     */

    private int getIntValue(Element ele, String tagName) {
        //in production application you would catch the exception
        return Integer.parseInt(getTextValue(ele,tagName));
    }

    /**
     * Iterate through the list and print the 
     * content to console
     */

    private void printData(){

        System.out.println("No of Employees '" + myEmpls.size() + "'.");

        Iterator<Employee> it = myEmpls.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next().toString());
        }
    }

    private void sortByAge(){
        Collections.sort(myEmpls);
    }

    public void run() {
        if (out != null){
            parseXmlFile(); 
            parseDocument();
            writeToStream();
        }
        if (in != null){
            readStream();
            sortByAge();
            printData();
        }
            // since i'm using the same class for both the producer and consumer thread 
            //   here, the code above functions as kind of a switch between these 2
            // modes of operation, by checking which pipe is initialized.


    }

    public void writeToStream(){
            try{
                out.writeObject(myEmpls);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                pout.flush();
                pout.close();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ErrorWS:" + e);
            }
    }


    public void readStream(){
            try{
                myEmpls = (List<Employee>) in.readObject();
                in.close();
                pin.close();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ErrorRS:" + e);
            }
    }


}
```

Here's the runner code :

```
package domAPI;

import java.io.*;

public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread t1,t2;

        try{
            PipedOutputStream pos1 = new PipedOutputStream();
            PipedInputStream pis2 = new PipedInputStream(pos1);

            t1 = new Thread(new ParserRunnable(pos1,1));
            t2 = new Thread(new ParserRunnable(pis2,1));

            t1.start();
            t2.start();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e);
        }

    }
}
```

My code might be pretty tricky to understand. Feel free to bombard me with questions, I'll be available. Also, most of the XML parsing code is originated from here : http://totheriver.com/learn/xml/xmltutorial.html#2

I'll just leave the XML here as well, if need be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Personnel>
  <Employee type="permanent">
        <Name>Seagull</Name>
        <Id>3674</Id>
        <Age>34</Age>
   </Employee>
  <Employee type="contract">
        <Name>Robin</Name>
        <Id>3675</Id>
        <Age>25</Age>
    </Employee>
  <Employee type="permanent">
        <Name>Crow</Name>
        <Id>3676</Id>
        <Age>28</Age>
    </Employee>
</Personnel>
```

The exception I get :

```
ErrorRS:java.io.IOException: Write end dead
No of Employees '0'.
ErrorWS:java.io.IOException: Read end dead
```

Comment: I've not worked on PipedOutput/InputStream before but from what you experience, I think the closing of the PipedOutputStream may cause inability for the PipedInputStream to read in data. Have you tried not call pout.close() before pin finish reading all the data? Maybe as a start, try not calling pout.close() and see how it behaves.

Comment: Why the two threads? Why not have the second thread read the XML directly? Where's the benefit? Don't add threads where you don't need them. Re your exceptions, are you recognizing end of stream? closing the pipes?

Comment: @anonymous Your suggestion doesn't make sense.  *Of course* closing the output stream causes 'inability' for the input stream to read data. It causes it to read end-of-stream instead. Not closing the output will just cause the input pipe to throw an IOException with an 'unconnected' or 'dead thread' message.

Comment: @EJP this is an university assignment which requires that I use pipes to communicate between threads, therefore I have to use at least two threads in this program. I am closing the pipes, as you can see.

Comment: @sergiu, I don't know the answer but this may help you. http://techtavern.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/whats-this-ioexception-write-end-dead/

Comment: @anon, thanks, I read that all before, but it didn't really seem to address my issue . I'll give it another go, maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some test code and I can reproduce the issue you're facing. But I don't see this problem IF the ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream is instantiated in their respective threads. For example.

```
public void run() {
    if (pout != null){
        parseXmlFile(); 
        parseDocument();
        writeToStream();
    }
    if (pin != null){
        readStream();
        sortByAge();
        printData();
    }
 }

public void writeToStream(){
    try{
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(pout);
        out.writeObject(myEmpls);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        pout.flush();
        pout.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ErrorWS:" + e);
    }
}

public void readStream(){
    try{
        in = new ObjectInputStream(pin);
        myEmpls = (List<Employee>) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        pin.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ErrorRS:" + e);
    }
}
```

You will need to remove the instantiation of ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream from the ParserRunnable constructor.

Comment: thank you, it works great. still a bit confusing as to why it did that, though

Comment: Yeah, I dunno either. I suspect it may be the ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream doing something with the underlying PipedInputStream/PipedOutputStream. I'll look at the JDK source and report back if I find something.